# How to edit manufacturers recovery image?

Tags: windows-10

I have a laptop with:

```
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System             100 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Reserved            16 MB   101 MB
  Partition 3    Primary            118 GB   117 MB
  Partition 4    Recovery          1024 MB   118 GB
```

`C:\OEM`

https://pastebin.com/FVdPv9jn

`C:\Recovery`

https://pastebin.com/HrgrSZ56

`E:\Recovery` (Recovery Partition)

https://pastebin.com/NBXd5fRT

And I want to "edit" manufacturer's recovery image (using `audit mode`, `Sysprep`, `Answer File`, `WIM` (or however was that windows program for editing windows images called))
to make it my "own".
Where do I need to start?

My end goal is to:

1. Edit Recovery-Image/Recovery-Image's Answer File so the `C:\Users` was moved to `D:\User` by default.
2. Similarly `C:\ProgramData` to `D:\ProgramData`
3. Similarly `C:\Program Files` to `D:\Program Files`
4. Similarly `C:\Program Files (x86)` to `D:\Program Files (x86)`
5. Stop my system from installing "few" default-Acer apps during recovery, and replace them with other apps of my choosing.

I am aware that I am trying to do something crazy, which would most probably be reset during the 1st windows upgrade, but nonetheless, I would like to test it. I already backed up the recovery partition and directories, I also did burn a System Recovery USB (made by Acer Recovery App).

I know that this question is quite broad, but I already know how to edit `Answer File` so that the location of system directories was set to "custom" values. At this moment I just need someone to point me in the right direction, and I'll manage the rest on my own.

Comment: Correct it is too broad>>>>>https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4254-create-custom-recovery-image-windows-10-a.html

Comment: You should rather use [Sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation).